# HTML Grid With Perfect Box

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a thumbnail like this: 
https://mmmastery.com/mastermind/

[image]

With the same style.

I have my html and css here: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lc97z7t/

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 80%; border: 1px solid red;">

<div class="box" style="width:20%">
    <img src="https://mmmastery.com/mastermind/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/infusionsoft-theory-of-automation.png">
    <h3>The Theory of Automation</h3>
    <button>Access Now</button>
</div>

<div class="box" style="width:20%">
    <img src="https://mmmastery.com/mastermind/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/infusionsoft-theory-of-automation.png">
    <h3>The Theory of Automation</h3>
    <button>Access Now</button>
</div>

<div class="box" style="width:20%">
    <img src="https://mmmastery.com/mastermind/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/infusionsoft-theory-of-automation.png">
    <h3>The Theory of Automation</h3>
    <button>Access Now</button>
</div>

<div class="box" style="width:20%">
    <img src="https://mmmastery.com/mastermind/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/infusionsoft-theory-of-automation.png">
    <h3>The Theory of Automation</h3>
    <button>Access Now</button>
</div>

<div class="box" style="width:20%">
    <img src="https://mmmastery.com/mastermind/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/infusionsoft-theory-of-automation.png">
    <h3>The Theory of Automation</h3>
    <button>Access Now</button>
</div>

<div class="box" style="width:20%">
    <img src="https://mmmastery.com/mastermind/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/infusionsoft-theory-of-automation.png">
    <h3>The Theory of Automation</h3>
    <button>Access Now</button>
</div>

</div>
```

Any idea what should I add to my css to make it look the EXACTLY the SAME and responsive when the screen size was being reduce.

If you could show me the JSFIDDLE as well.

Comment: How about the buttons and the responsiveness of it? How can I apply those exact style?

Comment: That's Bootstrap based. I'd suggest going that route. Note the `col-sm-6 col-md-4` in their source - that would indicate how the div resizes at different screen sizes for the Bootstrap framework. The 20% stuff isn't going to work how you'd like.

Comment: Welcome to SO mate

Comment: Can we just copy the CSS design instead?

Comment: You could I suppose but you'll still need Bootstrap to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="ld_course_grid col-sm-6 col-md-4">
   <article id="post-9603" class="thumbnail course sfwd-courses type-sfwd-courses has-post-thumbnail">


          <a href="//mmmastery.com/mastermind/the-theory-of-automation/" rel="bookmark">
        <img src="//mmmastery.com/mastermind/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/infusionsoft-theory-of-automation.png" class="attachment-course-thumb wp-post-image" alt="infusionsoft-theory-of-automation" />    </a>
          <div class="caption">
        <h3 class="entry-title">The Theory of Automation</h3>
              <p><a class="btn shadow  btn-block coursebtn" role="button" href="//mmmastery.com/mastermind/the-theory-of-automation/" rel="bookmark">Start Course</a></p>
      </div><!-- .entry-header -->
    </article><!-- #post-## -->
  </div>
```

You can definitely copy it

Comment: Do you have the JSFIDDLE?